# Node.js How to check if time string was within the last 5 minutes

Tags: node.js

I am writing some automation to check if emails are received from a certain server every 5 minutes.

Upon receiving each email i will extract the "time email was received" and run a check to make sure that time was in the last 5 minutes.

This is the "time email was received" string: 2022-07-06T09:55:10.590Z

Using Node.js how do i check to see if this time is within the last 5 minutes?

Comment: by comparing the difference of current time and time received.

Comment: Do you have example code of how that is done?

Comment: You can use [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) and [`Date.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first convert it to Date then calculate the difference.

To get the difference in minutes you can do something like this:

```
const dateFromString = new Date('2022-07-06T09:55:10.590Z')
const timeNow = Date.now();
const timeDifference = timeNow - dateFromString.getTime()
const timeDifferenceInMinutes = timeDifference / (1000 * 60)

console.log(timeDifferenceInMinutes)
```

then you can use `timeDifferenceInMinutes` to do your logic.

```
if (timeDifferenceInMinutes < 5) { // do something }
```

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what i wanted. Many Thanks